# Why setting up strictMode not working in Application without handler

Tags: android

When I want to set strictMode in Application without handler - no effects in Activities.

This code is working:

```
public class MyApp extends Appliction {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    new android.os.Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            setup_strict_mode();
        }
    });

    } 
}
```

This code is NOT working (no strict mode enabled in Activities)

```
public class MyApp extends Appliction {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    setup_strict_mode();

    }

}
```

Here is setup_strict_mode:

```
       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyDeath().build());
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog().build());
```

Though onCreate is running in UI thead, so why this is happening?

Comment: While I have not tried setting up `StrictMode` in a custom `Application`, I would have expected it to work without `post()`. Are there any interesting messages in LogCat when you skip the `post()` call?

Comment: @CommonsWare no interesting messages in logcat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok guys, I have found the solution. Its a bug described he

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35298